# ¿ Cual es basicamente la diferencia entre la anotacion @RequestParam y @PathVariable en Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Si alguien me pudiera explicar básicamente cual es la diferencia entre estas dos anotaciones y en que momentos saber si debo ocupar una o la otra.

Comment: En la documentación puedes encontrar la diferencia entre [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) y [`@PathVariable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html). ¿Cuándo vas a **usar**, una u otra? va a depender de lo que necesites hacer con los datos de la URI. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras El problema es que ese enlace está en inglés. Si la documentación oficial estuviese traducida, esta pregunta se podría cerrar, pero no es así

Answer (score 8):

Es simple. `@RequestParam` representa un valor que se envía en un pedido (request) como un parámetro adicional que va después del `?`.
Por ejemplo, para un request así:

```
GET /user?id=123
```

entonces usas la anotación `@RequestParam` así:

```
@GetRequest("/user")
public User getUser(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
...
}
```

Por otro lado, `@PathVariable` indica que nos referimos a datos incluidos dentro del mismo path del pedido, por ejemplo:

```
GET /user/123
```

```
@GetRequest("/user/{userId}")
public User getUser(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
...
}
```

A efectos prácticos, ambas formas se pueden usar y producen el mismo resultado, incluso en muchos casos se usan combinadas. Depende de como quieras estructurar tus endpoints. Si quieres que tu API sea bien *restful*, en general vas a usar `@PathVariable` y en algunos casos les agregarás algún `@RequestParam` también. Por ejemplo:

```
GET /user/123?friends=true
```

suponiendo que quisieras retornar un usuario incluyendo todos sus amigos.

Answer (score 2):

@PabloLozano tiene razón en su [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/380131/cual-es-basicamente-la-diferencia-entre-la-anotacion-requestparam-y-pathvari#comment681035_380131), al indicar que lamentablemente no existe documentación en castellano para `Spring`. Eso, junto con el hecho de que en la otra respuesta que han dado, se sugiere que *ambas formas se pueden usar y producen el mismo resultado*, cosa con la que no estoy totalmente de acuerdo, he decidido escribir esta respuesta.

**¿Parámetro de consulta o variable `URI`?**

En desarrollo web existen 2 conceptos bastante bien definidos: los parámetros de consulta (*query parameters*) y las variables de [`URI`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_de_recursos_uniforme) (*URI parameters*).

Los parámetros de consulta son usados (por lo general) para filtrar una petición. Son datos adicionales a la `URI` del recurso, en formato de par `nombre=valor`, separados por el carácter `&` y que se separan de la dirección `URI` usando el carácter `?`. Por ejemplo:

```
https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=es  // Castellano
```

Como se observa, el componente `URI` es `www.google.com/webhp`, y el parámetro de consulta es `hl=es`. Si deseamos cambiar el idioma en que se presenta esta página de Google, simplemente basta con cambiar el parámetro de búsqueda a otro valor, por ejemplo:

```
https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=ca  // Catalán
```

Las variables `URI`, por otro lado, se usan por lo general para identificar un recurso específico dentro del sistema. De esta forma se diferencian las entidades o modelos de datos sobre los cuales se realizan operaciones. Por ejemplo:

```
https://dominio.ext/user  // Ruta al modelo User
https://dominio.ext/post  // Ruta al modelo Post
```

Podemos usar una variables `URI` para traer un dato específico, por ejemplo:

```
https://dominio.ext/user/id  //Ruta al modelo User, cuyo identificador es id
```

**¿Cuándo debo usar una u otra?**

Volviendo a tu pregunta, `@RequestParam` y `@PathVariable` nos van a servir para extraer la información de acuerdo a su tipo, es decir, ya sean datos pasados como parámetros de consulta o variables `URI`.

**[`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html)**: nos permite extraer los parámetros de la consulta (par `nombre=valor`), además esta anotación de `Spring` nos permitirá establecer valores por defecto en caso de que la consulta no contenga parámetros. Por ejemplo:

```java
@GetRequest("/api/users")
public User getUser(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "Gabriel") String name) {
...
}
```

En este ejemplo se espera que la consulta tenga definido un par `nombre=valor`, y si no lo tiene se establece uno por defecto. Un ejemplo de `URI` para consumir esta ruta es:

```
/api/users?name=Pablo
```

**[`@PathVariable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html)**: Nos permite extraer la información que es parte de la estructura de la `URI` pero que no se trata como un par `nombre=valor` como el caso anterior.

Para poder usar esta anotación debemos indicarle de antemano al controlador que la estructura de la ruta contiene variables, mediante el uso del identificador `{<variable_name>}` donde `<varaible_name>` representa precisamente la variable a ser analizada o extraída de la ruta. Por ejemplo:

```java
@GetRequest("/api/posts/{postId}")
public User getPost(@PathVariable("postId") String postId) {
...
}
```

**¿Son intercambiables?**

A simple vista parece no haber una diferencia en su uso, ambas extraen información de la `URI`. Sin embargo, tratando de tener un buen diseño Rest, usaremos las variables `URI` para identificar un recurso único en nuestro sistema, mientras que los parámetros de consulta los usaremos para filtrar una solicitud.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que deseo la lista de todos los usuarios del sistema, esta es una petición que puedo escribir como:

```
GET /api/users
```

Ahora deseo pedir la lista de usuarios que se llamen *Gabriel*, entonces podría usar un parámetro de consulta:

```
GET /api/users?name=Gabriel
```

Esto me devolverá (si nuestra API está bien diseñada) la lista de todos los usuarios cuyo nombre sea *Gabriel*.

Por otro lado, supongamos que deseo ver un `Post` específico, entonces usaría una variable `URI`:

```
GET /api/posts/12345
```

Esta petición me devolvería la información del *Post* identificado por `12345`.

También podría ser válido usar un parámetro de consulta, por ejemplo:

```
GET /api/posts?id=12345
```

En fin, el uso de ambos tipos de anotaciones queda bastante claro en estos ejemplos, y un diseño consistente te obligará a usar uno u otro o una combinación de ambos, como ya vimos.

Mi recomendación es que uses la anotación `@RequestParam` para filtrar una consulta, y la anotación `@PathVariable` para identificar un recurso o entidad única.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo que haya que usar plural o singular, según el caso. En mi opinión, usar plural es lo indicado, porque estoy consultando, por ejemplo, un conjunto o colección de posts, luego de ese conjunto podré filtrar uno (o más).

Comment: @Alex, gracias por la aclaratoria. Tomo tu palabra